# Using function exists in php

Tags: php

I am using funcation exists in php but it is giving me back: bool(false). Where is the syntax error in my coding?

```
<?php

class Test{

  public function moneydays(){

    return null;

  }

}
var_dump(function_exists('$moneydays'));
?>
```

Comment: Your method is in a class.

Answer (score 2):

In your code example you have two errors:

1. `$moneydays` does not exist
2. `Test::moneydays()` is a **method**. Not a function.

To expand on #2 even if you had correct code `var_dump(function_exists('moneydays'));` it still wouldn't give you the results you expect because [`function_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) only will tell you if a function is defined the scope it is being used in. To test if a method exists you need to use [`method_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) which will check a *class* to see if it has the specified *method*.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you must use method_exists

```
method_exists('Test','moneydays');
```

example

```
echo method_exists('Test','moneydays') ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the `$` shouldn't be there. But additionally you are trying to find a function in a class so you need to use `method_exists`.

Since the method is not static, you MUST instanciate the class first, then check if it has a method:

```
$instance = new Test;
var_dump(method_exists($instance,"moneydays"));
```